# How can I resize the logo of my navbar without change my navbar height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my logo bigger. When I change the width, it gets bigger, but the height of the navbar becomes bigger as well. I don't want that, I want the navbar to stay the original height so that the logo fits it better.

Here is the navbar css:

```
#navbar {
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px #777;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

#navbar a {
    color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    width: 40px;
}

.navbar-brand span {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    color: #FFF;
}

#navbar-items .navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar-items .nav-item {
    margin: 0 1em;
}
```

Here is the Navbar screenshot:

[image: Navbar Screenshot]

I've changed the `#navbar-brand img` with `position: absolute` property like it was advised to me, and after I just resized the width via CSS until it better fit the navbar. I've also saved the image again with a closer zoom to make the logo clear and sharper.

Here is the edited css:

```
.navbar-brand {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;   
}

.navbar-brand img {
    width: 95px;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Edited Navbar Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried settings a fixed width for `#navbar`?

Comment: No! I've tried "height", but the result was the same, the navbar got bigger when i resized the image.

Comment: Hey @JustinTaddei i've put a fixed #navbar "height" atribute, and that worked now! Ty!!

Comment: Please provide your HTML code so we can properly answer your question. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi Davi. Please remember to mark whichever answer helped you the most as accepted (by clicking on the checkmark). This not only helps the person who took time to write the answer, but also others who may find your question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first.
You will probably need to do some additional settings, but for now.

```
.navbar-brand {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This solution work mate!
And put #navbar a fixed height worked too!
Ty!!

Comment: Yes, i had to readjust the span title positon adding margin-top atribute!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of how this can be achieved. I've excluded your bootstrap styling for the sake of brevity.
You can click "Run code snippet" below to preview it here on StackOverflow!

> Side note:
> This is a trivial problem, so I assume you're relatively new to web development? If so, I **highly** suggest you avoid CSS frameworks (such as bootstrap) until you have a firm grasp of vanilla CSS. You may find you don't need a framework at all. I'm a senior engineer and I never use a CSS framework for my personal projects. In fact, I don't even use one at my work :)

Some resources you may find useful:

- The basics of CSS grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout
- The CSS box model (this is vital to understand): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model
- Inline vs. block elements:

  - Inline: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements
  - Block: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px #777;
  background: #d66cbf;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / auto 1fr;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

#navbar .logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#navbar .logo img {
  /*
  Notice that I've used height instead of width.
  This has the same effect, but it's easier to
  match the height of the navbar if the logo
  is not a perfect square.
  */
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#navbar a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar .nav-link:hover {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar .nav-link {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a href="index.html" class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERspW.png" alt="Carol Rocha">
    <span>My Project</span>
  </a>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="quemsoueu.html" class="nav-link">Quem Sou Eu</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="meuscursos.html" class="nav-link">Meus Cursos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contatos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah! Im fairly new to web development. I knew that was a trivial problem too, but i couldn't find the correct solution to the problem on my research and i was advised about this community here. Yes im trying to learn more about vanilla CSS, that's why i got this work, i wanted to use this project as one of my portfolios projects and as well as a learning tool for me. Ty, i'll for sure follow your advice!

Answer (score -4):

Just edit the image and resize the image, 80x80 might work well for you, depends on your navbar size. But just resize your image

Comment: I'll try that and give you feedback! But i've not tried this because i think it could achive the same result as resizing the image bigger via css, you know, bigger image, bigger navbar too. But i'll give it a try!